# Calculate Normal Distribution Android Studio

Tags: java, android, math, statistics, distribution

I wanted to know how I can calculate the normal distribution of a number, like this in C#:

```
double result = Chart1.DataManipulator.Statistics.NormalDistribution(1.96);
```

I searched and found about a `nextGaussian` thing, but I couldn't understand how that is related to the normal distribution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the specific C# package, but the apache [commons math package](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/distribution.html) has extensive support for easily calculating different probability distributions, including the standard normal distribution function.

`NormalDistribution ndist=new NormalDistribution();
double result=ndist.cumulativeProbability(1.96);`

Comment: Yeah i downloaded that but I can't find how to use it in the Android Studio...       Could you help??  Thanks    @kasperjj

Comment: add: " compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math', version: '2.2' " to your gradle: see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math/2.2